# How to stream twitter mentions with tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, real-time, tweepy

I am currently using the following code, this gets the tweet and then passes it to a function that processes. This is not in realtime though.

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
mentions = api.mentions_timeline(count=1)
for mention in mentions:
   processText()
```

I have also looked in to streaming tweets but I have yet to find a way to stream mentions.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the [Streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/reference/post/statuses/filter) to filter on tweets containing @mentions. When you filter the stream using the track parameter, filter by the username you're interested in by including the username in your `track` parameter like so:

```
stream.filter(track=['twitterapi'])
```

This will return to you all tweets containing the string `"twitterapi"` in real-time, including @mentions (i.e. `"@twitterapi"`). See the [Twitter Streaming API `track` parameter](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters#track) for how this works. Then, you can use the result JSON to only take the tweets that actually @mention the user you're interested in. The result JSON looks like this:

```
{"retweet_count":0,"text":"Man I like me some @twitterapi","entities":{"urls":[],"hashtags":[],"user_mentions":[{"indices":[19,30],"name":"Twitter API","id":6253282,"screen_name":"twitterapi","id_str":"6253282"}]},"retweeted":false,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"place":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"coordinates":null,"source":"web","in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"favorited":false,"contributors":null,"geo":null,"truncated":false,"created_at":"Wed Feb 29 19:42:02 +0000 2012","user":{"is_translator":false,"follow_request_sent":null,"statuses_count":142,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","default_profile":false,"lang":"en","notifications":null,"profile_background_tile":true,"location":"","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"ffffff","followers_count":8,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/a1.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1540298033\/phatkicks_normal.jpg","contributors_enabled":false,"profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/365782739\/doof.jpg","description":"I am just a testing account, following me probably won't gain you very much","following":null,"profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1540298033\/phatkicks_normal.jpg","default_profile_image":false,"show_all_inline_media":false,"verified":false,"profile_use_background_image":true,"favourites_count":1,"friends_count":5,"profile_text_color":"333333","protected":false,"profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/a3.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/365782739\/doof.jpg","time_zone":"Pacific Time (US & Canada)","created_at":"Fri Sep 09 16:13:20 +0000 2011","name":"fakekurrik","geo_enabled":true,"profile_link_color":"0084B4","url":"http:\/\/blog.roomanna.com","id":370773112,"id_str":"370773112","listed_count":0,"utc_offset":-28800,"screen_name":"fakekurrik"},"id":174942523154894848,"id_str":"174942523154894848"}
```

That's a mess, but if you look in the `"entities"` object, you'll see `"user_mentions"`:

```
"user_mentions":[{"indices":[19,30],"name":"Twitter API","id":6253282,"screen_name":"twitterapi","id_str":"6253282"}]
```

Then, under `"screen_name"`, you see `"twitterapi"`, showing you that  the user [@twitterapi](https://twitter.com/twitterapi) was @mentioned.

Comment: `stream.filter(track=['@twitterapi'])` would be enough to get all mentions for `@twitterapi`